# Generic object comparison method with a variable number of method references for comparison

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I often have to compare to instances of a certain type for equality, but I do not need to compare everything, but only certain fields. I usually do it like this:

```
Comparator<SomeType> c = Comparator.comparing(SomeType::getNumber)
  .thenComparing(SomeType::getType)
  .thenComparing(SomeType::getSite)
  .thenComparing(SomeType::getAddition)
  .thenComparing(SomeType::getImportantFlag);

if (c.compare(old, new) == 0) {
...
}
```

As I have to to this really often, I am wondering if there is a generic way to do this. 
 All the objects I have to compare extend a certain base class. Is there a way to write a static method which can do all these comparisons for me? I was thinking of a static method which would have to parameters for the objects to compare and a vararg parameter for all the method references:

```
public static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(T left, T right, whatShouldIPutHere... fields) {
}
```

But I do not know how to pass the method references and how to use them in a comparator within the method. Can this be done in some way or is there a different approach I should try?

Comment: Does only your base class contain all the parameters on which you want to make the comparisons, or the child classes individually might as well contain some other parameters which should be used for the comparison checks...?

Comment: The child classes also contain some of the parameters which need to be compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to come up with something that seems to work:

```
public static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(T left, T right, Function<T,? extends Comparable>... fields)
{
    if (fields.length < 1) {
        return true;
    }
    Comparator<T> c = Comparator.comparing(fields[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
        c = c.thenComparing (fields[i]);
    }
    return c.compare(left, right) == 0;
}
```

Test classes:

```
class BaseType {
    String x;
    int y;
    public BaseType (String x, int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    String getX () {return x;}
    int getY () { return y;}
}

class SubType extends BaseType {
    String z;

    public SubType (String x, int y,String z) {
        super(x,y);
        this.z=z;
    }
    String getZ () {return z;}
}
```

Usage:

```
BaseType one = new BaseType("some",1);
BaseType two = new BaseType("some",2);
SubType three = new SubType("some",1,"else");
SubType four = new SubType("some",2,"else");
System.out.println (areFieldsEqual(one,two,BaseType::getX,BaseType::getY));
System.out.println (areFieldsEqual(three,four,SubType::getZ,BaseType::getX));
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `varargs` with generics will result in compiler warning like `Potential heap pollution via varargs parameter`. Generally to avoid such things we can provide few functions like below:

1. With single field:

   ```
   public static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(
     T first, T second, Function<? super T, ? extends Comparable> keyExtractor) {
       Comparator<T> comp = Comparator.comparing(keyExtractor);
       return comp.compare(first, second) == 0;
   }
   ```
2. With two fields:

   ```
   public static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(
         T first, T second, Function<T, ? extends Comparable> firstField,
         Function<T, ? extends Comparable> secondField) {
       Comparator<T> comp = Comparator.comparing(firstField).thenComparing(secondField);
       return comp.compare(first, second) == 0;
   }
   ```
3. Using `varargs`. As we aren't storing anything from `fields` we can use `@SafeVarargs` over this method:

   ```
   @SafeVarargs
   public static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(
     T first, T second, Function<T, ? extends Comparable>... fields) {
       if (fields.length < 1) {
         return true;
       }
       Comparator<T> comp = Comparator.comparing(fields[0]);
       for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
         comp = comp.thenComparing(fields[i]);
       }
       return comp.compare(first, second) == 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Edited to pass different type of properties.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea that you can use:

```
List<Function<SomeType, Comparable>> fieldsToTest = new ArrayList<>();
fieldsToTest.add(SomeType::getType);
fieldsToTest.add(SomeType::getSite);
System.out.println(areFieldsEqual(new SomeType(...), new SomeType(...), fieldsToTest));
```

`areFieldsEqual` method implementation:

```
static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(T left, T right, 
                                                   List<Function<T, Comparable>> fields) {
    Comparator<T> c = fields.stream().reduce(
        (l, r) -> 0, Comparator::thenComparing, Comparator::thenComparing);
    return c.compare(left, right) == 0;
}
```

Or, if you'd like to stick with the `varargs` parameter:

```
static <T extends BaseType> boolean areFieldsEqual(T left, T right,
                                                   Function<T, Comparable>... fields) {
    Comparator<T> c = Arrays.stream(fields).reduce(
        (l, r) -> 0, Comparator::thenComparing, Comparator::thenComparing);
    return c.compare(left, right) == 0;
}
```